# clicked() Signal for QListView

Tags: ruby, qt, listview, signals, click

I have a ListView and when I click in a row I need show more information about this row.
My problem is that the signal clicked() does not work for ListView.
When I initialize my application I get the following output in console

> Object::connect: No such signal QListView::clicked(index)
>
> Object::connect:  (sender name:   'appointments_list')

And when I click in a row nothing happend.

```
class GUICustomerAppointmentDetail < Qt::Widget

    def initialize (parent = nil, customer = nil)
        super(parent)
        ...     
        @ui.appointments_list.connect(SIGNAL('clicked(index)'), self, SLOT('load_data()')) 
    end

end
```

appointments_list is a Qt::ListView

I have replaced

> @ui.appointments_list.connect(SIGNAL('clicked(index)'), self,
> SLOT('load_data()'))

by

> connect(appointments_list.connect, SIGNAL('clicked(index)'), self,
> SLOT('load_data()'))

and I get

> Object::connect: No such signal QListView::clicked(index)
>
> Object::connect:  (sender name:   'appointments_list')
>
> Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'customerAppointmentDetail')

also

> @ui.appointments_list.connect(SIGNAL('clicked(index)')){ load_data() }

and I get

> Object::connect: No such signal QListView::clicked(index)
>
> Object::connect:  (sender name:   'appointments_list')

Please, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing happens, still not working but I found an [excellent gem](https://github.com/CeesZ/qt_connect/) and works great!

This gem allows me to write:

```
appointments_list.clicked.connect { load_data() }
```

Answer (score 1):

What's this index? Did you typedef it with Qmodelindex?

Try

`@ui.appointments_list.connect(SIGNAL('clicked(QModelIndex&)')){ load_data() }`

Instead of

```
@ui.appointments_list.connect(SIGNAL('clicked(index)')){ load_data() }
```

Comment: I get the same error: Object::connect: No such signal QListView::clicked(Qt::ModelIndex&)
Object::connect:  (sender name:   'appointments_list')